# Installing a buildPythonPackage Nix package into a mach-nix environment

Tags: python, package, nix

I am using a Nix flake to define a devShell with a python environment and certain dependencies available in it. This environment consists of a mixture of packages from the public PyPI repositories, and several packages internal to our organisation which are also stored as Nix flakes. For various reasons (compatibility with non-Nix users, good dependency resolution) I'm using [mach-nix](https://github.com/DavHau/mach-nix) to build the python packages and the environment.

However, I have a problem: one of the external packages (not under my control) is defined as an Nix flake but which uses the normal nixpkgs `buildPythonPackage` function instead of the mach-nix version. I need to include this package in my mach-nix environment. I cannot just rebuild it from source using mach-nix since the Nix build process includes various customisations that are required to get it to work in a Nix environment.

How can I get this package, build with the normal `buildPythonPackage` function, into my `mach-nix` environment?

## Things I've tried

There's more detail on the things I've tried at https://github.com/DavHau/mach-nix/issues/453, but they haven't worked so far! The closest I've got is defining an overlay like so (where [artiq](https://github.com/m-labs/artiq)) is the name of the package I'm trying to install, defined as an input to my flake):

```
artiq_override = self: super: {
  artiq = artiq.packages.x86_64-linux.artiq;
};

...

devShells.x86_64-linux.artiq = pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "artiq-environment";
  buildInputs = [
    (mach-nix.lib.x86_64-linux.mkPython {
      requirements = builtins.readFile ./requirements.in + ''
        artiq
      '';
      overridesPre = [ artiq_override ];
      providers = {
        artiq = "nixpkgs";
      };
    })
  ];
};
```

This fails however, with this error:

```
error: builder for '/nix/store/za9dczrb9937nspg6ikmyq0jpp8nxdy0-mach_nix_file.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       > Mach-nix version: master
       > Python: 3.9.12
       > Cause: Requirements conflict: artiq
       > The requirements which caused the error:
       >   artiq
       >
       > The given requirements might contain package versions which are not yet part of the dependency DB
       > currently used. The DB can be updated by specifying 'pypiDataRev' when importing mach-nix.
       > For examples see: https://github.com/DavHau/mach-nix/blob/master/examples.md
       >
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/za9dczrb9937nspg6ikmyq0jpp8nxdy0-mach_nix_file.drv'.
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

For the bold (to whom I am very grateful) here is an MWE:

```
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.follows = "artiq/nixpkgs";
    artiq.url = "github:m-labs/artiq";
    mach-nix.url = "mach-nix";
  };

  outputs =
    { self
      , artiq
      , nixpkgs
      , mach-nix
    }:
    let
      pkgs = import nixpkgs { system = "x86_64-linux"; };

      artiq_override = self: super: {
        artiq = artiq.packages.x86_64-linux.artiq;
      };

    in
    rec {
      inherit pkgs;

      devShells.x86_64-linux.default = pkgs.mkShell {
        name = "icl-artiq-environment";
        buildInputs = [
          (mach-nix.lib.x86_64-linux.mkPython {
            requirements = ''
              numpy  # (for example - I actually need more)
              pip
              artiq
            '';
            overridesPre = [ artiq_override ];
            providers = {
              artiq = "nixpkgs";
            };
          })
        ];
      };
    };
}
```